# Javascript - How do I access properties of objects nested within other Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

Within the context of React/Meteor I'm running into some surprising difficulty extracting information from a nested Javascript Object.

My data structure looks like this (taken from inspection in chrome dev tools:

```
Object {
id: "138451",
name: "Attendant",
 key: "Taiwan", 
defaultAnimation: 2, 
position: Object
 {
latitude:0.5,
longitude: -0.14
}
```

Within my React ComponentWillRecieveProps I see the following behaviour

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  console.log("its getting props");
  console.log(nextProps.markers[0]) // this works
  console.log(nextProps.markers[0].position) //so does this
  console.log(nextProps.markers[0].position.longitude) //breaks
```

I also tried setting 
 `var positionObject = nextProps.markers[0].position` but interrogating this object also fails. Please highlight my Javascript noobish mistake.

Thanks!

Comment: What is returning value nextProps.markers[0].position?

Comment: Hi Yasemin, this returns  >Object {latitude: 51.5193, longitude: -0.140725}

Comment: i dont understand why you dont access  to nextProps.markers[0].position.longitude

Comment: And what do you get with `nextProps.markers[0].position.longitude`? Is it `undefined`?

Comment: I get  0.140725 value.But i tried in console

Comment: Your code is right accroding to javascript.I think you miss the something in react.

Comment: Max, yes that does return undefined. It appears the problem is with React...